# Pass variables to PHPMailer get_file_contents

Tags: php

I am using the following code to send an email via (PHPMailer).

The script gets file contents from welcome.php (email template), how can I pass variables to the template? So I can customise the email template.

```
// SEND EMAIL NOTIFICATION TO USER
$mail = new PHPMailer();

$body = file_get_contents('emails/templates/carer/welcome.php');
$body = eregi_replace("[\]",'',$body);

$mail->AddReplyTo("support@carematch.org.uk","CareMatch");

$mail->SetFrom('noreply@carematch.org.uk', 'Carematch');

$address    = $_POST['email'];
$name       = $_POST['firstname'] . $_POST['lastname'];

$mail->AddAddress($address, $name);

$mail->Subject    = "Welcome to CareMatch";

$mail->AltBody    = "We have assigned you a unique ID and generated you a password."; // optional, comment out and test

$mail->MsgHTML($body);

if(!$mail->Send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Message sent!";
}
```

Comment: Instead of `file_get_contents()`, rather call a function that parses the template for tags and replaces the tags with the required content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way you could do is, you could add placeholders in your **welcome.php** and replace those placeholders with actual values, once you get the contents, using [str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) function, like:

```
...
$searchArr = ["YOUR-PLACEHOLDER-FIRST", "YOUR-PLACEHOLDER-SECOND"];
$replaceArr = [$yourFirstVariable, $yourSecondVariable]

$body = file_get_contents('emails/templates/carer/welcome.php');
$body = str_replace($searchArr, $replaceArr, $body);
...
```

The palceholders `YOUR-PLACEHOLDER-FIRST` and `YOUR-PLACEHOLDER-SECOND` are to be added to **welcome.php** file

Comment: humm, it is based on template frameworks structures?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function I use often to give me PHP templates that uses PHPs output buffer to capture the rendered template.

It provides much more flexibility compared to a static array of placeholders using any kind of find and replace approach.

```
function loadTemplate($template, array $properties = array()){
    $output = "";

    if (file_exists($template)) {
        extract($properties);

        ob_start();

        require($template);

        $output = ob_get_contents();

        ob_end_clean();
    }

    return $output;
}

$data = [
    "foo" => "bar"
];

$message = loadTemplate("/path/to/email.phtml", $data); // <p>bar</p>
```

email.phtml

```
<p><?php echo $foo; ?></p>
```